# Cross validation with Training/Testing sets

Tags: machine-learning

Is it possible to do the evaluation with cross validation and using training/testing sets? I  understand cross validation vs holdout evaluation, but I am confused about if we combine them together.

Comment: If you are doing CV you don't have a train and test sets, instead all of the data is used for both training and testing at different times.  I don't see any advantage of combining the techniques, perhaps you can clarify what you hope to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Both cross-validation and holdout evaluation are widely used for estimating the accuracy (or some other measure of performance) of a model. Typically, if you have the luxury of a large amount of data available, you might use holdout evaluation, but if you are a bit more restricted, you might use cross-validation.

But they can also be used for other purposes - in particular, model selection and optimization - and one might commonly want to do these things as well as estimating the model's accuracy.

For example, you might wish to carry out feature selection on your model (choose among several versions of the model, each if which has been built with a different subset of variables), and then evaluate the final chosen model. For the final evaluation, you might reserve a test set for holdout validation; but in order to choose the best subset of variables, you might compare the accuracies of the models built on each subset, as estimated by a cross-validation on the training set.

Other aspects of models could also be optimized using this mixed approach such as, for example, a complexity parameter from a neural network or the ridge parameter from ridge regression.

Hope that helps!